# django 1.7: allow_empty_file not working in ImageField

Tags: python, django

I can't get my Django form to make an ImageField optional.

If I do this

```
class TestUploadForm(forms.Form):
    pic_upload=forms.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True)
form2=TestUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
pdb.set_trace()
```

and then pass a file to it, it is happy:

```
(Pdb) request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {u'pic_upload': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test2.png (image/png)>]}>
(Pdb) form2.is_valid()
True
```

if I don't pass a file to it, it doesn't validate although `allow_empty_file` is set to True:

```
(Pdb) request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {}>
(Pdb) form2.is_valid()
False
```

If I put `blank=True` instead of `allow_empty_file=True`, I get an error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'
```

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
pic_upload = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

`blank=True` is used in model definition, not forms.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error when you put `blank=True`  because it is a form field, not a model field. Use `required=False` instead.